# Implement Per Property Change Tracking

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# app using the MVVM pattern and I was wondering what would be the best way to implement change tracking on a per property basis. I currently have INotofyPropertyChanged implemented and flag whether or not the whole object is dirty, but some of the requirements I have to implement is they want to be able to show an image by the text box on the UI for every property that has been changed.

Basically my View Models all have a private field that is my class containing the data from my DataAccess Layer. So basically a class will look like this:

```
private BusinessObj _data


public Name
{
    get{ return _data.Name;}
    set
    {
       if(_data.Name != value)
       {
           _data.Name = value;
           PropertyChanged("Name");
           IsDirty = true;
       }
    }
}
```

My data access layer is basically serializing and deserializing XAML profiles for configuring our products.

Comment: I'd store the originals and compare the current value to the original.  This will give you the ability to revert changes as well.

Comment: Does your object need to track this? As your object already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, can you subscribe to that event and keep a list of the properties that have been changed?

Comment: @hvd If I tracked that I would get an update every time they entered a character into the text box and I'm only interested in if it is different than the original so I can let the UI know it should draw the asterisk

Comment: @cadrell0 I was wondering if that would be acceptable, but I tried serializing my original object and storing that then changing the _data value to the original, but the UI didn't update as those are private variables and NotifyProperty change isn't on those. Also with that approach to notify the UI I would need a boolean for every single property that the ui could bind to.

Comment: @twreid But you do mark the object as dirty in that case, don't you?

Comment: @twreid Anyway, you can still use that method if you also implement `INotifyPropertyChanging`: you can cache the old value (if it isn't known yet) just before the property is changed, and after it's changed, compare it to the old value.

Comment: Yes, the whole object gets marked as dirty, but not individual properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ObservableCollection` in your Model Class and have your UI subscribe the event when the observable business data collection changed.

in Model View

```
public class BusinessObjList : ObservableCollection<BusinessObj>
{
   public BusinessObjList() : base()

   public void AddBusinessObj
   {
       // your own manipulation
   }
}
```

in UI

```
BusinessObjList BL = new BL();
BL.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(bl_CollectionChanged);

static void bl_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // handle the change in UI.
}
```